# Which oauth token type is better for node js based applications. JWTs or Opaque? Where to store each one of them

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, token, access-token

I am using Open ID connect protocol for authenticating and authorizing the users in a node js based application. With Oauth2 we can use two types of token formats - JWT and opaque tokens. Which one suits better for Node JS based applications? 
What should be the storage strategy for each of these two token types? Is it good to store these two tokens inside the session cookie

Answer (score 0):

There is no better token type for Node.js, the choice criterias are elsewhere. It all depends whether you want your token to hold information or not, and whether you want a **stateless** application or not.

The JWT holds user information, that means you don't have to call a particular endpoint to retrieve the user info after authentication is successful. It's also signed by the backend which means the backend can verify the authenticity of the token by checking its signature, and it doesn't need to store the token anywhere (i.e: in session storage or in the database) between two requests. In that regard, the backend is **stateless**.

On the other hand, an opaque token is lighter (less network overhead on every authenticated request) but it requires one more request to retrieve user information, and it requires the backend to store the token in order to verify further requests.

Comment: Thanks Guerric, for opaque tokens, you mentioned backend to store them. Do you mean database or some kind of cache or as session variable? Cannot we store them in the session cookie?

Comment: If you store them in your database, then your backend is **stateless** which means it is closer to RESTful, but you can also store them in the session cookie, it will work perfectly fine too, as long as you don't need horizontal scalability for your app